# Index is not getting used

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

This is excerpt from Tom Kyte's book.

> "We’re using a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T` query (or something similar)
>   and we have a B*Tree index on table T. However, the optimizer is full
>   scanning the table, rather than counting the (much smaller) index
>   entries. In this case, the index is probably on a set of columns that
>   can contain Nulls. Since a totally Null index entry would never be
>   made, the count of rows in the index will not be the count of rows in
>   the table. Here the optimizer is doing the right thing—it would get
>   the wrong answer if it used the index to count rows."

As far as I know indexes come into picture when we use a WHERE clause. Why index come in the above scenario? Before countering him I wanted to know the facts.

Comment: *"index comes in picture when you used where clause"* - that's not the only scenario for the index usage. A simple select statement can very well utilize an index if optimizer thinks so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the indexing of `NULL` values by including a constant in the index:

```
create index t_table_col on t(col, 0);
```

The `1` is a constant expression that is never `NULL`.

Comment: My question is how index comes here in picture. we are not using where clause. Does oracle count the indexes whenever we use count(*)?

Comment: @OnkarTiwari It can, if there is a suitable index and the optimiser chooses to use it.

Comment: Note that you can save yourself one byte of storage per row by using zero instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Database does not store NULLs in the B-tree index, see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/indexiot.htm#CNCPT1157)

> Oracle Database does not index table rows in which all key columns are
>   null, except for bitmap indexes or when the cluster key column value
>   is null.

Because of this, if the index has been created on a column that **may contain null values**, the database cannot use this index in a query like: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T`. Even when the column does not contain any NULLs, the optimizer doesn't know this unless the column has ben marked as `NOT NULL`.

---

According to [the documentation - FAST FULL INDEX SCAN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/indexiot.htm#GUID-D54BD14D-0065-4B61-B2F6-5567913B16CD)

> **Fast Full Index Scan**
>
> A fast full index scan is a full index scan in
>   which the database accesses the data in the index itself without
>   accessing the table, and the database reads the index blocks in no
>   particular order.
>
> Fast full index scans are an alternative to a full table scan when
>   both of the following conditions are met:
>
> The index must contain all columns needed for the query.
>
> A row containing all nulls must not appear in the query result set.
>   **For this result to be guaranteed, at least one column in the index
>   must have either:**
>
> - **A NOT NULL constraint**
> - A predicate applied to the column that prevents nulls from being
>     considered in the query result set

So if you know that the indexed column cannot contain NULL values, then mark this column as `NOT NULL` using `ALTER TABLE table_name  MODIFY column_name column_type NOT NULL;` and the database will use that index in the query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T`
If the colum can have nulls, and cannot be marked as `NOT NULL`, then use a solution from @Gordon Linoff's answer.

Answer (score 2):

> "As far as i know indexes comes in picture when you used where clause. "

That's one use case for indexes, when we want quick access to rows identified by specific values of indexed column(s). But there are other uses.

Counting rows is one. To count the number of rows in a table Oracle actually has to *count each row* (because statistics may not be fresh enough), which means literally reading each block of storage and counting the rows in each block. Potentially that's a lot of reads.

However, an index on a NOT NULL column also has an entry for each row of the table. Indexes are much smaller than tables (typically only one column) so an Index block contains many more entries than a Table block. Consequently Oracle has to read far fewer Index blocks to get the count of rows than scanning the table would require. Reading fewer blocks is faster than reading more blocks.

This isn't true if the table only has indexes on nullable columns. Oracle  doesn't index null values (unless the index is a composite index and at least one column is populated) so a count of the entries in an index couldn't guarantee to be the actual count of the table's rows.

Another common use case for reading indexes is to satisfy a SELECT statement where all the columns in a projection are in one index, and the index also services any WHERE conditions.